# How to prevent HTML5 form validation on non-submit button?

Tags: html, validation

A form with reset and submit buttons, but both are causing HTML5 validation.  When the user clicks reset, I just want the fields cleared.  Assuming this is default action for any form button, and not just submit, how do I prevent the default action, but still run the custom action?

```
<button data-ng-click="reset()">Reset Form</button>
<input type="submit" data-ng-click="main.$valid && post('Check')" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
```

[image]

Comment: You could try using `<input type="reset"/>`, since that's a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the form an `onsubmit` handler containing `e.preventDefault()`, and in your "submit" handler call `form.submit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the button's type attribute to button:

```
<button type="button" data-ng-click="reset()">Reset Form</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set its type attribute this way:

```
<button type="button">Reset Form</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET if you use HTML validation, to prevent other buttons from submitting your form you can make the attribute UseSubmitBehavior to FALSE. It will prevent it from submitting the form and causing validation.

```
asp:Button ID="btnBack" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnNewGameBack_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-1" Text="Back"/>
```